# enviar caracteres especiales (ñ, Ñ, tildes) en Pyautogui

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, pyqt5

Estoy usando Pyautogui para enviar mensajes automaticos y uso el metodo write() para enviar el mensaje a la caja de mensajes de whatsapp todo funciona bien salvo los carateres espciales(ñ, Ñ, vocales tildas) el la caja de texto aparcen todas la letras menos los caracteres especiales.

Comment: Estas usando codificación `utf-8`?

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré es con la librería pyperclip, haciendo un copiar y pegar:

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('ñ')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
pyperclip.copy('Ñ')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```